# Error de compilación asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Cuando ejecuto la app y compila, al momento de mostrar todo. Me muestra un error en tal línea con el mensaje  de error:

> CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is
> not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Lo cual no me deja y me marca el rojo la línea del `html.raw()`

```
<h3 class="box-title">
    Solicitudes
    @Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("Agregar", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info float-right" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("Agregar", "<i class=\"fas fa-plus\"></i>"))
</h3>
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en mi web.config

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="es-MX" uiCulture="es-MX"/>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
      <remove name="RoleManager"/>
    </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity" value="true"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Y pues ya después tengo las referencias que uso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Busque en el web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
```

Y agregue el `System.Runtime`  en el ensamblaje de la siguiente manera:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>     
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />   
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Ya con eso ya pudo ejecutarse sin problema alguno.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo quitar el @Html.Raw y dejarlo como

```
@Html.ActionLink("Agregar", "Create", new {@class="btn btn-info float-right"})
```

o usar simplemente un Link en fin en cuenta al dar click te va redirigir a una nueva vista

Comment: No es eso, me sigue tirando el mismo error.

Comment: comparte tu codigo del Web.config y que version estas utilizando del framework lo vez dandole clic izquierdo y propiedades del proyecto

Comment: Uso la version 4.5.2

Comment: @Luis Código en lugar de pantallazos por favor.